# Encapsulating Data Outside of a Class

Tags: c++

I'm writing some C++ functions that will produce data that may or may not be processed later by those functions (but will not be processed anywhere else). These functions are the 'low-level' for some higher-level, GUI changes.

I'm currently wrapping these functions in a separate namespace, and have declared a static (internally linked) vector to contain these objects within the vector (the objects are defined as a struct, also contained within the namespace). Thus, the general structure:

```
namespace Foo
{
    struct Bar
    {
        string data;
    };

    void func1();
    void func2();
    static std::vector<Bar> cachedBars;
}
```

I really don't need a class for this, and am not interested in resorting to a singleton. Is this solution sufficient? Specifically, is internally-linking a namespace-scope collection the best way to restrict access to that collection, as well as avoiding all of the pitfalls of global variables, or is there a better way?

Comment: It's not avoiding any pitfalls of a global, what with it being a global and all.

Comment: Is that a header file?  If so, you will get a separate copy of cachedBars everywhere you include the file.

Comment: @Cat: I was hoping it was, at least, global--.

Comment: If the only guys that can access cachedBars are func1() func2() then just put the vector in .cpp  file, so you never show it to anyone.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes then what does the line containing cachedBars do?

Comment: @Kostya better yet place the definition of Bar there too since the function declaration don't depend on it.

Comment: @AnonMail 1) declaration 2) You are right that if possible you can hide Bar as well.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Is there any benefit in declaring the static in a header? It seems like it would lead to linker errors rather than compile ones.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus What pitfalls arise here? I don't see any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I would put that just the declaration of the functions in the .h

```
void func1();
void func2();
```

And the hidden stuff in the .cpp under an anonymous namespace.

```
namespace
{
    struct Bar
    {
        string data;
    };

    static std::vector<Bar> cachedBars;
}

void func1() { /* do something */ }
void func2() { /* do something else */ }
```

With that, func1 and func2 will be accessible from everywhere but Bar and cachedBars will just be accessible by the functions defined in the .cpp, so func1 and func2. Provided there is nothing else in the .cpp, only func1 and func2 will be able to modify cachedBars.

Just in case you don't know, an anonymous namespace will have the same effect than the static keyword when used to modify visibility. However, it's more powerful since you can hide nearly anything with it.

Comment: Wouldn't this muddy up the global namespace, though?

Comment: Not really. The anonymous namespace is not the global namespace but a new one, local to the file. So there will be no effect on the global namespace. As I said, it's just like using the static keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. What I usually do in this case is putting the `func1()` and `func2()` functions in the `.h` file. While the static vector goes inside `.cpp` together with function bodies.

I suspect that you will need to show the `struct Bar` in `.h` file because usually functions return or take that structure as a parameter. But if no one needs to know about the struct -- then hide it in `.cpp` as well. (It is also possible that only pointers or references are passed/returned. Then you can forward-declare it.)

Comment: That's helpful for interface concerns, but what about the vector itself? Is namespace-scope internal-linkage an effective way of managing access to a collection outside of a class, or is there a better way?

Comment: It's even easier to hide in the .cpp with under an anonymous namespace. Then, only the functions defined in the .cpp will be able to access all that.